# Deployer v4.2.1 fatal error "undefined function" with officially endorsed 3rd party recipes out of the box

Tags: laravel, namespaces, php-deployer

After a basic install of PHP deployer v4.2.1 I find that it does not work (see below) with the officially endorsed 3rd party recipes out of the box. I am fairly new to Deployer. Here is what I did.

I installed PHP deployer v4.2.1 with:

```
composer require --dev deployer/deployer
composer require --dev deployer/recipes
```

And of course I ran `dep init` to get set up with a basic `deploy.php` file.

In my `deploy.php` I added the following at the top:

```
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/laravel.php';
require 'vendor/deployer/recipes/local.php';
require 'vendor/deployer/recipes/rsync.php';
require 'vendor/deployer/recipes/npm.php';
require 'vendor/deployer/recipes/cachetool.php';
```

Then I set my git repository, server info, etc. My final `deploy` task runs the `local:prepare` command and this is where it chokes with an odd error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Deployer\desc() in /home/vagrant/Code/MyProject/vendor/deployer/recipes/local.php:76
```

Obviously there is some namespacing issue going on.

Somehow I figured out that I can get around the issue if I make a local copy (outside vendor dir) of the 3rd party recipe files, and then modify them so the calls to `desc(...)` follow `task(...)` like `task(...)->desc(...)`. This works, but now I am running into other issues and I feel like I'm headed down the wrong path. I feel like this is an unacceptable work around for what is basically a fresh installation. The `laravel.php` recipe that comes bundled with Deployer calls `desc(...)` all by itself and not after `task(...)->desc(...)`, so it seems to me that the 3rd party recipes should be able to handle it, but they throw an error. (Even with `namespace Deployer;` declared at the top, or perhaps because of it.)

Anybody else encounter this issue? Is there something simple I forgot to add to `deploy.php` so I don't have to modify vendor files?

Comment: everything in vendor directory is not meant be changed manually, try deleting vendor directory contents and run composer install so it can start installing everything again also it will execute commands if any in composer.json if problem persists try posting composer.json content and PHP versions

Comment: I didn't edit the vendor files directly. I made a local copy of the vendor files outside of the vendor directory and included those. Whatever the case, I just tried another experiment on a fresh project and it still errored out: (a) mkdir myEmptyDir (b) cd myEmptyDir (c) composer require --dev deployer/deployer (and also deployer/recipes) (d) dep init [choose laravel], (e) edit deploy.php and after laravel recipe is included, add "require('vendor/deployer/recipes/local.php');" (f) add a dummy 'test' task that does nothing (exit after). Even with this basic setup, running "dep test" errors out.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Nevermind I found the answer. Posted separately here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Going to answer my own question here...)

I had a globally installed `dep` that was version 3.3.0 (installed manually without composer), and this was the file that was running everytime I typed `dep` instead of the newer, locally installed project version of `dep`. So it was trying to run 4.2.1 recipes with 3.3.0 deployer.

**Solution:**

Run this from the command line:

```
php vendor/bin/dep deploy [server]
```

instead of:

```
dep deploy [server]
```